# How to use case class define a extractor?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, extractor

I want to use case class match Seq[Byte] as List defined, but a compiler error occurred.

use case class with compiler error

```
case class :: (head: Byte, tail: Seq[Byte])        
def doMatchWithCaseClass(queue: Seq[Byte]) = {    
  queue match {
    case h :: t => println("Good!") //can't compile
    case _ => println("God!>_<")
  }
}
doMatchWithCaseClass(Seq(1,2,3))
```

Compiler error:

```
Error:(93, 14) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : ::
 required: Seq[Byte]
      case h :: t => println("Good!") //can't compile
             ^
```

**UPDATE with @isaias-b post code**

```
  final case class :::: (override val head: Int, override val tail: Seq[Int]) extends Seq[Int] {
    override def length: Int = tail.length + 1
    override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = (head :: tail.toList).toIterator
    override def apply(idx: Int) = {
      1.toByte // just for simple
    }
  }
```

match code:

```
  def doMatchWithCaseClass(queue: Seq[Int]) = {
    queue match {
      case h :::: t => println("case class - Good! ^_^")
      case x =>
        println(s"case class - God >_<! $x")
    }
  }
```

test code:

```
  doMatchWithCaseClass(Seq(1,2,3))
```

console result:

```
> case class - God >_<! List(1, 2, 3)
```

above code not any compile error but it isn't my expecting result.
Hope someone could point the mistake.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is the desired solution, but this seems to work:

```
case class ::(override val head:Int, override val tail: Seq[Int]) 
  extends Seq[Int] { 
    def iterator = ??? 
    def apply(idx: Int): Int = ???
    def length: Int = ??? 
}
```

As the compiler error tells you, it found an instance of type `::` but required a `Seq[Byte]`. I have provided a sample with `Int` which now extends a `Seq[Int]` this allowed me to proceed a step further.

```
scala> case class ::(head:Int, tail: Seq[Int]) extends Seq[Int]
<console>:10: error: overriding method head in trait IterableLike of type => Int;
 value head needs `override' modifier
       case class ::(head:Int, tail: Seq[Int]) extends Seq[Int]
                     ^
```

So i added the `override` keyword and after another error, the `val` keyword as well. Then there were the 3 given abstract methods left to define, i provided the stubs being printed on the console. With this it was possible to execute the following:

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3) match { case ::(a, as) => "list"; case _ => "empty!" }
res5: String = empty!
```

Hopefully this disappears when providing correct implementations for the 3 required methods. However, the compiler doesn't complain anymore...

## Update 1

@badcook pointed out that...

> Your :::: case class doesn't work because subtyping is going "the wrong way" so to speak; although your :::: is a Seq, queue is not a :::: and the latter is what matters in the pattern matching.

And he is right, extending always feels weird when usually trying to favour composition over inheritance. Now [here is a comparison from Martin Odersky's online book about scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html#24.6), which points out the differences between extractors being implemented using `case class`es against using separate `un/apply` and `un/applySeq` methods.

> Even though they are very useful, case classes have one shortcoming: they expose the concrete representation of data.

Separating the extractor from the representation, leverages *representation independence*, in his terms. This begs a question: Is this a hard choice because of technical limitations, or a soft choice? Most of the time it is not a hard choice:

> So which of the two methods should you prefer for your pattern matches? It depends. If you write code for a closed application, case classes are usually preferable because of their advantages in conciseness, speed and static checking. If you decide to change your class hierarchy later, the application needs to be refactored, but this is usually not a problem. On the other hand, if you need to expose a type to unknown clients, extractors might be preferable because they maintain representation independence.
>
> Fortunately, you need not decide right away. You could always start with case classes and then, if the need arises, change to extractors. Because patterns over extractors and patterns over case classes look exactly the same in Scala, pattern matches in your clients will continue to work.

However, there is a part describing now that there are exceptions to this guideline!

> The email addresses discussed in this chapter were one such example. In that case, extractors are the only possible choice.

## Update 2

I am not 100% sure again, if this holds for the current scenario as well, speaking if you are facing the case where you hit this limitations. @badcook seems to know it, because another thing he pointed out was:

> Based on your comments to other replies, it seems like you already know about extractor objects and are really just looking to see if case class can save you the effort of typing out your own unapply and unapplySeq methods for a preexisting type.
>
> The answer is unfortunately no. You've gotta use unapply and/or unapplySeq (they're not so bad :)).

We later clarified this, so that I now think to understand it myself as well. I'll sum up the extract of the conversation by reciting myself. For this assume to have the following `case class Y(x: X)`:

> The provided def `unapply(y:Y):X` method from the `case class Y` is strongly bound to it's input and output types. The only way to put something else into it, is using inheritance. This leads to trouble then.

And in my current understanding this trouble is called *representation dependence*.

Comment: I have reognized `::` should be extends with Seq and so sorry, the code get a "god" not "good"…,hope someone come here.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you organize such resource.As you say, I must use extractor to match `Seq` type.at last, What's "But, why" mean?

Comment: I have added the new information to the post, and removed the "why". I wanted to know why we would have to choose an extractor here instead of case classes.

Comment: ha...,the question you have referred actually.I just prepare it in follows: If you want to extract a abstract class or final class, the case class can't do. Because case class only extract class it extends, besides, final class it can't extend and abstract class is useless to extract. `Seq` is abstract we have tried and String is final class. The paper you referred example, email address,try to extract String of address to Tuple. So, in the two cases, we must use **object companion**'s `unapply` method to extract data.

Comment: and what's representation dependence? it feeling so abstract

Answer (score 1):

You can match directly on a `Seq` with a slightly different extractor.

```
def doMatch(queue: Seq[Byte]) = {
  queue match {
    case h +: t => println(s"Head: $h and tail: $t")
    // You could also do case Nil =>...
    case t      => println(s"Bad: $t")
  }
}

doMatch(List(1, 2, 3)) // Head: 1 and tail: List(2, 3)
doMatch(List())        // Bad: List()
```

**Edit:**

It seems you're not just trying to match on `Seq`s but have more general pattern matching on your mind.

Based on your comments to other replies, it seems like you already know about extractor objects and are really just looking to see if `case class` can save you the effort of typing out your own `unapply` and `unapplySeq` methods for a preexisting type.

The answer is unfortunately no. You've gotta use `unapply` and/or `unapplySeq` (they're not so bad :)).

Your `::::` case class doesn't work because subtyping is going "the wrong way" so to speak; although your `::::` is a `Seq`, `queue` is not a `::::` and the latter is what matters in the pattern matching.

The pattern matcher sees your first `case`, and tries to look for a relevant `unapply` method. Unfortunately, the generated `unapply` method of `::::` has the signature `:::: => Option[(Int, Seq[Int])]`, and `queue` is not a `::::` so the match fails.

On the other hand

```
object JustWriteUnapplyAndLifeWillBeGood {
  def unapply(xs: Seq[Int]): Option[(Int, Seq[Int])] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) None else Some(xs.head, xs.tail)
}
```

works just fine.

```
Seq(1, 2, 3) match {
  case JustWriteUnapplyAndLifeWillBeGood(head, tail) => 
    println(s"head: $head, tail: $tail")
} // head: 1, tail: List(2, 3)

// Look Ma, no prefix!
Seq(1, 2, 3) match {
  case head JustWriteUnapplyAndLifeWillBeGood tail =>
    println(s"head: $head, tail: $tail")
} // head: 1, tail: List(2, 3)
```

or `override` the generated `unapply` method of `::::` with the correct signature.

Comment: Can you give an explanation, why it is necessary to use `apply` and `unapply` in this case? What are the exact limitations? See also my answer for some credible resources.

Comment: A case class `Y` is essentially syntactic sugar for a bunch of predefined methods which all have arguments and/or outputs of type `Y`. For any methods that take in `Y` as an argument (e.g. `unapply`), this means that in order for the method to be callable on a type `X`, `X` must be a subtype of `Y` (i.e. contravariance). If `X` already exists and does not already `extend` `Y`, Scala has no way of retroactively doing so without modifying the definition of `X`. In this case the user has no way of modifying a `Seq` so no case class `Y` can have the correct `unapply` method.

Comment: Makes sense, somehow. The provided `def unapply(y:Y):X` method from the `case class Y` is strongly bound to it's input and output types. The only way to put something else into it, is using inheritance. This leads to trouble then.

Comment: oh,I think you point the importent things that `Seq` is abstract class but `Seq(1,2,3)` is `List` so case class can't match `Seq` forever,isn't it?

Comment: another things I want to say is pattern match not support coveriant. but I think it not bad eddect if it is coveriant.at least,`Seq` can match all of its subclass with my case class.: )